# i want to change position of 'short description of single product page in wordpress astra theme

Tags: woocommerce, datastax-astra

Woocommerce Product Page: how to change position of 'short description', 'price' and 'variation description' in astra theme ..

woocommerce hooks are not working as the theme overrides the woocommerce.
i used the following code to remove the short description from single product page, but its not working
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

Answer (score 0):

It could be the astra theme messing with your priorities.
I've used this to move my categories around and it works with an Elementor theme:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 4 );
```

I think your priority of 20 for the excerpt is correct..